# Old EDA software for Mac called "EDS"

Tags: circuit-design, cad, eda

So we have some old schematics at work that were ostensibly made by an EDA software called <strike>"RUN"</strike> "EDS" probably sometime in the early 90s. Supposedly this software ran under the [Classic Mac OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_Mac_OS). I have an old Mac available that would probably run this software. However it seems notoriously difficult to find any information on this software - probably because "run" is such a difficult search term. Does anybody have any information on this or maybe even know a way how to obtain a copy of this software? I would like to open some of these files. Are there any converter tools or anything for this software?

**Edit 1:** Now I think this software was actually never called "RUN". I dug around on our server at work and I think it was called EDS (I found some old documentation and the executable was called "RUN EDS 3.2.1" and the person I talked to always referred to it as "RUN"). I googled around a little bit and it looks like it was made by a company called "Quickroute" from the UK. They are mentioned [here](https://www.diyaudio.com/community/threads/does-anyone-here-use-ouickroute-eds-3-design-pcb-design-software.30481/) and [here](https://de.beta-layout.com/forum/121/2193/). Surprisingly little information on this software on the internet.

**Edit 2**:

I checked out the [McCAD EDS](http://www.mccad.com/) software, but I couldn't open any of the files with it. So I contacted them and they told me that McCAD EDS is not the same software as QuickRoute EDS:

> Lucas;
>
> Unfortunately, QuickRoute EDS is not a product of ours and we do not
> have a means for importing the layout other than through our GView
> product which can deconstruct a Standard Gerber Plot file into
> something editable within our layout environment.
>
> Regards
>
> McCAD Tech Support

So the hunt is still on ...

Comment: you say "ostensibly made by": How do you know?

Comment: also, consider asking on https://apple.stackexchange.com/ or https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MarcusMüller: An older co-worker gave me the name.

Comment: Um, honestly, do they maybe remember the company behind that software, as well? Might actually be something designed in-house or by some minor local company and "the internet" could not possibly know about that...

Comment: @MarcusMüller Definitely not in house. But it might be some small company. I was also very surprised this morning when I googled around and couldn't find anything about it. I will try to find out some more information about the software on Monday.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: I edited some information to the question. Looks like this mysterious sofware was actually called "EDS". Even though internally everyone referred to it as "RUN" here.

Comment: http://www.mccad.com/FREEMACSTUFF.html <--- this EDS maybe?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Oh, interesting. This might be it. I just filled out their form to download EDS, but I got "404 not found ". So this site might be defunct. I see if I can contact someone there.

Comment: hm, according to [this](https://www.applefritter.com/replica) website, you can get the EDS Lite from the apple store [here](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/schematics-se500/id512388910?mt=12). Haven't tried it.

Comment: hm, mccad's [windows version download site](http://mccad.com/WinXP_EDS.html)  seems to work without problem. Maybe that can open your legacy files!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I contacetd McCAD and unfortunately they told me that QuickRoute EDS is not their software and they cannot open these files.

Answer (score 2):

I used this software for decades.

http://www.mccad.com/

McCAD from VAMP.

The guy's name is George and he's in Los Angeles. He's as old as the hills. And so am I.

Here are the free tools: http://www.mccad.com/TotallyFreeMenu.html

Comment: Thank you for your response! However, I contacted McCad and they say that McCad EDS is  not the same as QuickRoute EDS. I edited their response into my question.

Comment: but that means you know that this is QuickRoute! https://archive.org/details/tucows_254175_Electronic_Design_Studio

Answer (score 0):

Just as support for above comments (Daide Andrea and Marcus Muller), dowloaded link to win10 home. Trial version (100days) works ok. This is the interface if it helps (know you asked for MAC, but I only have win here).

[image]